# Travis CI Fails to install pods

Tags: cocoapods, travis-ci

I'm trying to get the Travis build to pass for a [open source project](https://github.com/BlurredSoftware/BSWFoundation/tree/swift3), but to no luck:

The sample project's [Podfile](https://github.com/BlurredSoftware/BSWFoundation/blob/swift3/BSWFoundationPlayground/Podfile) looks like this:

```
abstract_target 'Common' do

#Swift 3 Pods
pod 'BNRDeferred',  :git => 'https://github.com/bignerdranch/Deferred.git', :branch => 'swift-3_0'

pod 'BSWFoundation', :path => '../BSWFoundation.podspec'

target 'BSWFoundationPlayground'
target 'Tests'
```

end

But the [build is failing](https://travis-ci.org/BlurredSoftware/BSWFoundation/builds/161001167) with this error:

```
Pre-downloading: `BNRDeferred` from `https://github.com/bignerdranch/Deferred.git`, commit `4fad78faf79c6f386f780bffb7c78ecdfbd1f10b`
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'BNRDeferred'.
```

Any idea what might be going on? I'm using the Xcode 8 `osx_image` on Travis and the project's `pod install` works fine locally

Comment: Any solution on this?  Just ran into the same issue